# Set of sentences in L with no non-logical symbols that are satisfiable iff L-structure is even

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

[image]

This is a past paper question for my revision. L is defined as first order language with only the unary function {f} as its non-logical symbol.

I have so far found a sentence for the first part of c - it uses a function symbol, and I believe that for the second part of c I cannot find such a sentence without a predicate or function symbol, though I can't figure out how to prove this. If so, then in part d the set of sentences can't be finite, else we could take the conjunction of them as our sentence in this part of c.

I am also struggling to find a set of sentences as asked for in part d. I can't really think of how to split A into two parts without a function or predicate symbol.

Comment: For d, you can find a sentence for each $n$ saying that if $\cal A$ has $n$ elements then $n$ is even. For the second part of c, if you only have equality, then a single sentence can't characterise the finite structures with an even number of elements.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure on:
-How you'd construct such a sentence for d
-How one proves that its impossible to characterise the finite structures with an even number of elements with just equality

Comment: I've added an answer addressing part d. I misread part c. Can you clarify that $\cal L$ in part c is the language comprising a single unary function symbol $f_{\cal A}$?

Comment: Yep that's true, and L' is a stand in for any other language

Comment: I see. I find part c rather murky: it's not to hard to come up with a sentence the $\cal L$ that has finite models of every even cardinality and no finite models of odd cardinality, but that isn't what the question is asking for. If you just have equality, then any sentence is equivalent to a (finite) propositional combination of assertions of the form "the universe has at least $n$ models".

Comment: Hi, I came across this whilst looking for answers to a similar problem, (OP seems to be doing the same papers as me it seems). I thought it will be a useful exercise to attempt this also. I am struggling to think up of a sentence for c) characterising evenness. Satisfying one direction seems straightforward: $\psi = \forall x ( f(f(x)) = x \land \neg f(x) = x )$ seems to do the trick. However this does not guarantee the other direction - it relies on a specific chosen property of $f$, but not all $L$ structures will have an $f$ with this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses part d.
Define sentences $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mu_n &\equiv \exists x_1\exists x_2 \ldots \exists x_n\forall x(x = x_1 \lor x = x_2 \lor \ldots x = x_n) \tag*{$n = 1, 2, \ldots$}\\
\nu_1 &\equiv \mu_1 \\
\nu_n &\equiv \mu_n \land \lnot \mu_{n-1} \tag*{$n = 2, 3, \ldots$}
\end{align*}
$$
So ${\cal A} \models \mu_n$ asserts that $\cal A$ has at most $n$ elements and ${\cal A} \models \nu_n$ asserts that it has exactly $n$ elements.
Now let $\Psi = \{\lnot \nu_1, \lnot \nu_3, \ldots, \nu_{2n+1}, \ldots\}$. Then if $\cal A$ is a finite structure, ${\cal A} \models \Psi$ iff $\cal A$ has an even number of elements.